# Is there a way to prevent listening on a particular port range, even when somebody is an administrator?

Tags: windows, networking

I saw an interesting feature on a company machine that i'm interested in implementing on machines I manage.

On such a machine, Windows asked me to restart to install some updates, I did that. Afterwards, I find some rather strange issues, e.g. vcxsrv not working.
After some troubleshooting, I have found that none of the ports between 5950 and 8070 are "listenable".
For example(I'm using python3 here),
`python -m http.server 5950` will result in error `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions`
`python -m http.server 5949` works perfectly.

Those ports that are not "listenable", I'm pretty sure they are not occupied. I've checked by running cmd as administrator, then run command `netstat -ano|findstr 5950` etc.

How might that have been done on that company laptop.  I ask because i'm interested, incase I want to do something similar on a system I'm managing.

Is there any standard method, perhaps even native to Windows, that does that?

Below is a screenshot to help explain:
[image]

Comment: Issues specific to corporate IT support and networks are off topic, see [On-Topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic). Please talk to your IT department.

Comment: I didn't think this is off-topic. maybe I didn't make my question clear enough. To boil it down, the question is really "what is this tech called". Or, If I'm an admin of a Windows system, to achive this type of behavior, what tech do I look into.

Comment: You don't have to mention that it's a company laptop, there's no need to mention it, you even have admin access to it.  Also before asking what technology might cause that, (which is a question that might baffle some people), ask what might cause that. If that's resolved then you could look at what technology might create that effect.

Comment: also to help troubleshoot it, try testing lots of ports. and put output to a file. e.g. maybe use the python line in this kind of command `for /L %f in (1,1,5) do @ECHO %f`   use `%f` as port number, and `>>` results to a file.. see which ports work and which fail, that might help give some clues. You can also try safe mode with networking, that might start less processes so if it works it might give some clues.

Comment: In my view the info that this is a company laptop is quite valuable, a lot of times roll outs via GPO etc. unintentionally effect other components as well (in those cases asking admins won't solve the issue most of the times). Info on recent roll outs might contain helpful hints, so it would be good if you could ask anyway.

Comment: @barlop thank you for the tips. How many ports are affected is not really important I guess, knowing how to do that for one port would be good enough. I tried different search queries on google, but you can probably guess, the results are all about how to do `netstat` and how to change firewall etc.

Comment: @SparedWhisle  i'm not talking about counting ports, but knowing all the ports that are affected is important as clues in the detective work in figuring out what on earth is going on

Comment: a similar question is asked here though the OS is linux https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18947356/node-js-app-cant-run-on-port-80-even-though-theres-no-other-process-blocking-t

Comment: We cannot tell you what technology was used. You should ask your IT folks what they are using. Also, I disagree with Barlop: we cannot solve this problem for you BECAUSE it is a company system. We will not propose circumventing their controls, and the systems they're using and policies they have applied are the reason you are unable to listen on these ports.

Comment: @music2myear TBH, I'm not looking to circumvent any control, just genuinely interested in knowing what's happening. Even if you can tell me "this is done by a technique called XXX", I'm pretty sure I won't be able to circumvent it. I'm pretty sure keeping it a secret is not the right way to impose an limitation.

Comment: @barlop `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` shows the ports that are reserved (not listenable). Trying to delete a rule would result in "access denied" error. like I said to @music2myear, knowing it wouldn't allow me to circumvent anything.

Comment: @music2myear It's called "excludedportrange". `netsh interface ipv4 show excludedportrange protocol=tcp` command shows me exactly what ports are reserved. trying to make any changes results in error `access denied`. So I think my question is a fair question, an answer would be something like "check netsh help doc and look for excludedportrange"

Comment: interesting.. my computer doesn't list any ports for "administered port exclusions", made me wonder, whether the command was being done on your computer at boot, but apparently, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5254330/reserve-a-tcp-port-in-windows   "By default port reservations are persistent across reboots". You could point it out to your IT guys and ask them why they do that (or maybe not 'cos you don't want to encourage them or make them think of, blocking more!)

Comment: It's really interesting. If you google the error, pretty much all articles tell you to check if the port is already ocupied. I don't think I've seen this mentioned as a possible cause for the error anywhere before. Now I know what it is, how my IT does it and how they gave the the "access denied" error is a totally different question(if I want to circumvent the control that is).

Comment: @SparedWhisle got it reopened,  I think if you are flirting with asking about circumventing a measure put in by an IT dept (or it's a bit suggestive of it), then the question might not be considered very legitimate by some here.. . But if your question is, as in my edit, then it's ok and as you see, has been reopened.  Also, you  could post your netsh finding as an answer